# How render product wishlist link functionality in custom template (phtml) in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, phtml, wishlist

How to display wishlist link (with functionality) in custom phtml file using template file in magento 2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try something like the following code:

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>' .
__('Add to Wish List') . '</span></a>
```

Refer the below file and related block for more details

> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\listing.phtml

Make sure your custom module should use

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "wishlist": {
                    "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hi @Krishna, can you please update for Add to compare and send to an email as well please?