# add static block on top of header

Tags: magento2, static-block, php-7

I am trying to customize Magento top header with some custom static block and also want to change and relocate existing link  and icon like wish-list.
I created  static block for top-header social icon and try to add this default.xml file. But unlucky .

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
                <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_socail_link"  after="header.panel">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_socail_link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block> 
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/astrokapoor_logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">180</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">69</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
         <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content.target" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/skiptarget.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target_id" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>        
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!--<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />!-->
        <move element="wish-list-link" destination="panel.top.links" />
        <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

similarly I want add currency logo on top and wish-list logo after cart item.please see screenshot .its my exact requirement.any help
[image]

Comment: Please share your full code which is in `default.xml`.

Comment: kunj@ you there

Comment: kun@please check  this

Comment: You are using header.panel under header.panel. please check your code.

Comment: Sukumar Gorai @I am new here can you help me regarding This

Comment: ` after="header.panel"` I think this is wrong. after that flush cache try again.

Comment: kunj 6 @iremove this and all thing working . can you let me know how can i add wish list icon

Comment: You can do by custom CSS and for code check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142299/how-render-product-wishlist-link-functionality-in-custom-template-phtml-in-mag

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" before="minicart" name="header.wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::link.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Now create new file in your theme like this: `/{theme Pcakage}/{theme name}/Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml`And add this code in that file:

```
<div>
    <a href="<?php  echo $this->getUrl('wishlist') ?>" class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?php echo __('Add to Wish List');?> </span></a>
</div>
```

Now flush the cache.

Comment: kunj@I need include wishlist  option on header  with  cart icon,

Comment: @sanjayyadav I have updated my code/answer.

Comment: kunj @it's print  a  (.) after logo

Comment: Please share what have you done.

Comment: kunj @I  follow your instruction  but now success

Comment: Please share your code with full xml and path

Comment: app/design/frontend/mynewtheme/newtheme/Magento_Wishlist/templates and for xml  path is  app/design/frontend/mynewtheme/newtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: That code must work. Did you flushed cache and clear cache?

Comment: I did all thing

Comment: Is that in local? May I have website URL?